# Searching through a list in an if statement - best Python implementation

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionary elements - each element is constructed as:
"filename":xyz, "people":"Luke, Leia, Anakin, Obi Wan","event":"","date":"Jan 1,2020"
where the filename is unique, the people field can have a variable number of names, and other fields can be blank or not

The user inputs the names they want to search on, comma delimited in this case say "Luke, Anakin", I want to return any filenames that have Luke and Anakin in the people field

data_list is the list of dictionary elements I want to sort through (obtained via opening a csv file and reading it - code skipped).

```
people = input("list of people (comma delimited)
people_list=people.split(sep=',')

for row in data:
    if people_list[0] and people_list[1] in row['people']:
         file_list=file_list.append(row['filename'])
```

the problem is that I don't know how to write **people_list[0] and people_list[1]** in a format that allows people_list to be a variable size (that is the input to be "Anakin, Luke, Obi Wan" or "Anakin, Sidious", in a method that is efficient.

Basically I'm looking for something that will work like:

```
for row in data:
    if people_list in row['people']:
        file_list=file_list.append(row['filename'])
```

when I try that I get " 'in' requires string as left operand, not list " error message

Comment: Look in to using sets instead of comma delimited strings; https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: you might need to split `this_p_list = row['people'].split(',')`  , convert `people_list` and `this_p_list` in sets, finnaly run: `people_list.issubset(this_p_list) `

Comment: Using a set did not occur to me.  This is far more reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator expression combined with the `all()` function:

```
if all(name in row['people'] for name in people_list):
```

This translates as "if all the names in `people_list` are also in `row['people']`"

Also you might want to make a slight change to your input.  If they enter `Luke, Leia` at the input prompt and then you call `split(sep=',')`, it splits **only** on a comma, so  `Leia` will end up with a space at the beginning.

You can use `sep=', '` to split **exactly** on comma-space, but then you will have a problem if they enter only a comma without a space.

Also, as others have pointed out, this is a good argument for storing the names in your dictionary as a list or a set, not as a delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use python's `Set` and `.issubset()`

eg.

```
people = input("list of people (comma delimited)")
people_set = set(people.split(sep=','))

# Assuming the 'people' entry in the data is also a set
for row in data:
    if people_set.issubset(row['people']):
         file_list=file_list.append(row['filename'])
```